# HTML video show once per session

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I have a simple full screen background video that plays once the page was loaded. The code I'm using is straightforward (please ignore the WordPress-specific bits):

```
<video autoplay poster="<?php the_field('home_background_image'); ?>">
     <source src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/dist/intro.mp4';?>"  type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

What I would like to achieve is to play this once per session – so if the user navigates away from the homepage, but then comes back for whatever reason, the video is not displayed at all.

What would be the best way to go around this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is just to use cookies. Here's an example straight from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

```
if (document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)someCookieName\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") !== "true") {
  alert("Do something once here!");
  document.cookie = "someCookieName=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
}
```

That obviously a confusing bit of regex, but there's lot of libraries out there for dealing with cookies in a much simpler fashion.